# I need to Graphs like UML diagrams or Nodes for my app

Tags: open-source, javascript, angular, typescript

I am looking for any open-source angular based module to integrate with the app I am working on my aim is to have options for drag and dropping the elements which should be connected with other nodes, is there any open-source Typescript based library available, I have found mx-graph but that is written in pure JavaScript and   I am looking for any angular module for this purpose.
Looking forward to your suggestions.

here is what I want to achieve.
[image: The view i have achieved with mx-graph but i want any typescript library]

[image: Here is my requirement.]

Thanks in Advance,